# Server Error in '/' Application. While trying to Access stackoverflow

Tags: google-chrome

I am writing this from my mobile, So I keep it short. After installing Avast Free Antivirus, I cannot open the Stackoverflow webpage anymore, I get the Error "Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error. Description: an Exception occurred while Processing your request.additonally, another Exception occured while executing the Custom Error Page for First Execution. The request has been Terminated. Help, i am a total web noob  :(

Comment: SO was experiencing some outage. This should be fixed by now.

Comment: It's expected, cuz stackoverflow was down just now for ~20 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by following this guide:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_other-mso_o365b/server-error-in-application-cleared-my/78b3a5d6-78d4-4c42-8a0f-638fae7c9fb7?auth=1

1.Open your browser (such as Chrome) -> use Ctrl +shift+ delete to clear all browser data again.

2.Go to Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials > under Generic Credentials, remove all credentials.

3.Open Chrome and check the result again.

Answer (score 0):

same problem happened!

Just use proxy [ultrasurf](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultrasurf-security-privac/mjnbclmflcpookeapghfhapeffmpodij/related?hl=en) extension! (Any other proxy also will work) No need to delete any certificates or credentials.

In case you delete any certificates or credentials it might cause some errors in future(some applications may crash).